# Setting src through DOM vs Comparing src values

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom, boolean, src

I have an img tag like this

```
<img id="fish" src="">
```

And I set and changed the src of img throught a setInterval function randomly

```
var randFish = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

if(randFish == 0) document.getElementById('fish').src = "images/fish.png";
else if(randFish == 1) document.getElementById('fish').src = "images/fishbone.png";
```

This piece of code works well and image path is added successfully to the src, but when I try to compare if this src is equal to that path, it returns false always

```
console.log(document.getElementById('fish').src == "images/fish.png"); //output: false
console.log(document.getElementById('fish').src == "images/fishbone.png"); //output: false
```

When I try to return in console the src

```
console.log(document.getElementById('fish').src); //output: file:///C:User/Desktop/.../images/fishbone.png
```

Using path of image this way to compare works, but why this happens and is there a clever solution than using the entire path like "file:///C:User/Desktop/.../images/fishbone.png"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, as you saw when you tried

```
console.log(document.getElementById('fish').src);
```

the `element.src` property returns the full url of the element. What you are looking for is the value of the `src` attribute. So try:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('fish').getAttribute('src') == "images/fish.png");
```

which should return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const img_  = document.getElementById('img_');
img_.fish_  = ['fish.png', 'fishbone.png'];
img_.path_  = 'images/';

img_.change_ = function(){
  let random_ = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.fish_.length);
  img_.src = `${this.path_}${this.fish_[random_]}`;
  console.clear(); console.log(img_.src);
}
```

```html
<img id="img_" src="" />
<button onclick="img_.change_();">Randomly change fish</button>

<!--
   /   = Root directory
   .   = This location
   ..  = Up a directory
   ./  = Current directory
   ../ = Parent of current directory
   ../../ = Two directories backwards
-->
```